# How to load multiple sliders handling between 2 values with input and output with noUiSlider?

Tags: javascript, jquery, addeventlistener, nouislider

I'm stuck.. I want to create multiple range sliders with noUiSlider. Each slider has to handle between to values [0,100]; (min=0, max=100,). Moreover i need a output and input of values by handler and entered by User.

See my current code here:

```js
  function data ( element, key ) {
   return element.getAttribute('data-' + key);   
  }
  
  var connectSlider = document.getElementsByClassName('slider'); 
  var input0 = document.getElementsByClassName('input-format-0');
  var input1 = document.getElementsByClassName('input-format-1');
  var inputs = [input0, input1];
  
  function createSlider ( slider ) {
   
    noUiSlider.create( connectSlider,{
     start: [0, 100],
     connect: false,
     step: Number(data(slider, 'step')) || 1,
     range: {
      'min': [0],
      'max': [100],
     },
     tooltips: true,
     connect: true,
     format: {
      to: function (value) {
       return value + '%';
      },
      from: function (value) {
       return value.replace('%', '');
      },
     }
    });
  }
  connectSlider.noUiSlider.on('update', function( values, handle ) {
   inputs[handle].value = values[handle];
  });
  
  Array.prototype.forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('.slider'), createSlider); 

 

  function setSliderHandle(i, value) {
   var r = [null,null];
   r[i] = value;
   connectSlider.noUiSlider.set(r);
  }

  // Listen to keydown events on the input field.
  inputs.forEach(function(input, handle) {

   input.addEventListener('change', function(){
    setSliderHandle(handle, this.value);
   });

   input.addEventListener('keydown', function( e ) {

    var values = connectSlider.noUiSlider.get();
    var value = Number(values[handle]);

    // [[handle0_down, handle0_up], [handle1_down, handle1_up]]
    var steps = connectSlider.noUiSlider.steps();

    // [down, up]
    var step = steps[handle];

    var position;

    // 13 is enter,
    // 38 is key up,
    // 40 is key down.
    switch ( e.which ) {

     case 13:
      setSliderHandle(handle, this.value);
      break;

     case 38:

      // Get step to go increase slider value (up)
      position = step[1];

      // false = no step is set
      if ( position === false ) {
       position = 1;
      }

      // null = edge of slider
      if ( position !== null ) {
       setSliderHandle(handle, value + position);
      }

      break;

     case 40:

      position = step[0];

      if ( position === false ) {
       position = 1;
      }

      if ( position !== null ) {
       setSliderHandle(handle, value - position);
      }

      break;
    }
   });
  });
```

```html
<link href="https://refreshless.com/noUiSlider/distribute/nouislider.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://refreshless.com/noUiSlider/distribute/nouislider.js"></script>

      <div class="rangefilter">
       <div class="slider"></div>
       <ul>
        <li class="left"><input class="input-format-0" type="text"></li>
        <li class="right"><input class="input-format-1" type="text"></li>
       </ul>
      </div>
```

Would be really nice if somebody could help me. 
Thank's.
Best regards.

Answer (score 1):

Faced a similar problem. Spent 3 days on the solution. The solution is not optimal. But now this is the best I can offer.

HTML:

```
<div class="custom-range-slider">

  <span class="custom-range-slider__input-text">from</span>
  <input class="custom-range-slider__input custom-range-slider__input--from" type="number">

  <span class="custom-range-slider__input-text">to</span>
  <input class="custom-range-slider__input custom-range-slider__input--to" type="number">

  <div class="custom-range-slider__track"></div>
</div>

<br>
<br>
<br>

<div class="custom-range-slider">

  <span class="custom-range-slider__input-text">from</span>
  <input class="custom-range-slider__input custom-range-slider__input--from" type="number">

  <span class="custom-range-slider__input-text">to</span>
  <input class="custom-range-slider__input custom-range-slider__input--to" type="number">

  <div class="custom-range-slider__track"></div>
</div>

<br>
<br>
<br>

<div class="custom-range-slider">

  <span class="custom-range-slider__input-text">from</span>
  <input class="custom-range-slider__input custom-range-slider__input--from" type="number">

  <span class="custom-range-slider__input-text">to</span>
  <input class="custom-range-slider__input custom-range-slider__input--to" type="number">

  <div class="custom-range-slider__track"></div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
var rangeSlidersTrack = document.querySelectorAll('.custom-range-slider .custom-range-slider__track');
var rangeSlidersInputFrom = document.querySelectorAll('.custom-range-slider .custom-range-slider__input--from');
var rangeSlidersInputTo = document.querySelectorAll('.custom-range-slider .custom-range-slider__input--to');
var rangeSliderInputs = [];

for(var i = 0; i < rangeSlidersTrack.length; i++) {
    rangeSliderInputs.push([rangeSlidersInputFrom[i], rangeSlidersInputTo[i]]);
}

[].slice.call(rangeSlidersTrack).forEach(function(slider, index) {
    noUiSlider.create(slider, {
        start: [0, 500],
        connect: true,
        range: {
            'min': 0,
            'max': 500
        }
    }).on('update', function(values, handle) {
        rangeSliderInputs[index][handle].value = parseInt(values[handle]);
    });

    function setSliderHandle(i, value) {
        var r = [null,null];
        r[i] = value;
        slider.noUiSlider.set(r);
    }

    rangeSliderInputs[index].forEach(function(input, handle) {

        input.addEventListener('change', function(){
            setSliderHandle(handle, this.value);
        });

        input.addEventListener('keydown', function(e) {

            var values = slider.noUiSlider.get();
            var value = Number(values[handle]);

            // [[handle0_down, handle0_up], [handle1_down, handle1_up]]
            var steps = slider.noUiSlider.steps();

            // [down, up]
            var step = steps[handle];

            var position;

            // 13 is enter,
            // 38 is key up,
            // 40 is key down.
            switch (e.which) {

                case 13:
                    setSliderHandle(handle, this.value);
                    break;

                case 38:

                    // Get step to go increase slider value (up)
                    position = step[1];

                    // false = no step is set
                    if ( position === false ) {
                        position = 1;
                    }

                    // null = edge of slider
                    if ( position !== null ) {
                        setSliderHandle(handle, value + position);
                    }

                    break;

                case 40:

                    position = step[0];

                    if ( position === false ) {
                        position = 1;
                    }

                    if ( position !== null ) {
                        setSliderHandle(handle, value - position);
                    }

                    break;
            }
        });

    });

});
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/w3oLvnyj/6/)